# Getting the max of a column based on criteria in another column

Tags: excel

I have some data like:

| Group | Alpha | Numeric (Sometimes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Z |
| 1 | B | X |
| 1 | C | Y |
| 2 | B | Z |
| 2 | A | X |
| 2 | C | Y |

A, B, and C repeat in that not necessarily in that pattern but always in groups together, while the numeric column is often numeric data that varies or text. How can I get the max numeric value for a group for just A and B using a repeatable formula (or a lambda function)? I have tried using vlookup for A and B in the range composing a group and passing the numeric column to MAX() but when the numeric column has text, MAX() and MIN() fail (even though it supposedly ignores text). Any ideas on how to get it to return correctly?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`DMAX()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dmax-function-f4e8209d-8958-4c3d-a1ee-6351665d41c2) function?

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, you want the MAX for each unique GROUP number where the ALPHA is either A or B, right?